# Replacing text in files recursively using windows

Tags: powershell, replace, foreach

So I can change text in a file like this:

```
(gc file.name) -replace 'Foo', 'Bar' | sc file.name
```

Now I want to do this for each file in this directory. In DOS I would do:

```
for %f in (*.*) do (gc %f) -replace 'Foo', 'Bar' | sc %f
```

I get a helpful message telling me the syntax is wrong, but it doesn't tell me what the right syntax is. I bet someone here can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
foreach ($F in dir){ (gc $F) -replace 'Foo', 'Bar' | sc $F }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2) to get the files in the directory and a loop of your choice, [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) in this case.

```
Get-ChildItem path\to\targetDirectory -File | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Raw) -replace 'Foo', 'Bar' |
        Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

If you want to do this *recursively* for all files under `targetDirectory` you would just include [`-Recurse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2#-recurse).